# unity - occlusion bugging on crossing inside a house

Tags: unity-game-engine

As the picture shows, the occlusion is buggy on other side walls of the house.

When player is inside, it shows correctly objects that are inside the house.

When player is outside, it gets buggy on objects that are inside and on the other side of the house (the trees).

The entire house is static and I baked occlusion again many times.

It only happens on this place, so is there any specific way to handle this kind of occlusion?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you will have to use custom lighting instead of using Unitys default lightning system on walls that is the best case to see the wall having occulsion enabled.
because camera would only process those gameobjects more easily
which has got lightining added via materials manually.

then try making the adjecent walls with lights on it -> static as well .
This should work .

Comment: I'm sorry for not understanding, but could you detail a bit more? Is this a problem with occlusion or lights? You mean I should not use default Unity Directional Light for my map? Any suggestion on what to use instead?